# Undefined object property whenever I loop through it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, loops, object

I'm trying to loop over an Object that I pass in from the Parent component but its properties return undefined.

I understand the first thing to check would be that the Object is actually not empty, but when I print it in the same useEffect below, it contains all of the data and information that I need. It's only when I loop through it and try to access the individual keys or properties that it is undefined

```js
const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState < string[] > ([]);
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(salesTaxData) // This returns the correct existing data
    if (salesTaxData !== undefined) {
        Object.keys(salesTaxData).map(item => {
            if (salesTaxData[item].internalCode !== undefined)
                console.log(salesTaxData[item]
                .internalCode) // This keeps returning undefined even when the first console log above clearly indicates it does have a value
        })
    }
}, [salesTaxData]);
```

EDIT: Extra information:

[console.log of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEFDl.png)
This image shows how the original object looks. It shows that both gstHst and pst keys are populated, but when I try to loop over them, they're empty. I also tried the suggestions in the replies below doing it with the for (const x in x) way and the JSON method to console log, but neither method fixed me issue.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(salesTaxData))` instead

Comment: Agree with Konrad - console.log does not necessarily log the data in the moment you call it because you pass the object by reference.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including a value of `salesTaxData` that causes the problem

Comment: Generally speaking, a better approach to loop over an object is to use "for in" loop:


const object = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };



for (const property in object) {
  console.log(`${property}: ${object[property]}`);
}

Comment: Added an image in the post showing the original object and the result of the loop. Thank you!

Comment: You misunderstood use. Please use `console.log(JSON.stringify(salesTaxData))` and see if the data is really there

Answer (score 1):

### Beware `console.log` in asynchronous code

What is displayed in the console may not be the value at the time of that `console.log` was executed, but rather the value at the time you are viewing it. This is a peculiar behaviour of browsers. I think it is intended to be helpful, but I personally find it annoying.

You would be better to reword your console.log as follows:

```
const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState < string[] > ([]);
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("salesTaxData:",JSON.stringify(salesTaxData, null, 2)) 
  if (salesTaxData !== undefined) {
    Object.keys(salesTaxData).map(item => {
        if (salesTaxData[item].internalCode !== undefined)
            console.log("salesTaxData[item].internalCode:",JSON.stringify(salesTaxData[item]
            .internalCode,null,2) 
    })
  }
}, [salesTaxData]);
```

### Use `JSON.stringify` to force conversion into a string immediately

By doing this, even if the value of `salesTaxData` changes later, what is displayed on screen will not change, because it has already been stringified.

The `,null,2` just adds some tidy formatting to the output.

### Paste the resulting console.log output as *text*, not an image

This means it is

(a) searchable

(b) copiable

(c) more quickly viewable

And therefore more likely to get your question answered.

### Incidentally if you are not processing an array to return a new array, use `.forEach` rather than `.map`

`.map` is generally used when you are processing an array to make another array, with each element in the first array being mapped to a new element in the second array. e.g.

```
const doubled = values.map(x=>2*x)
```

When we see the `.map` function we are usually expecting what is inside to it to have no side effects, but rather simply return a new value.

If we are in fact intending to have side effects, we usually signal this to future readers, by using the `.forEach` function:

```
values.forEach(x=>{console.log(x, " times two is ", x*2})
```

What I am saying is that your line:

```
    Object.keys(salesTaxData).map(item => {
```

would be easier for future programmers to understand if written:

```
    Object.keys(salesTaxData).forEach(item => {
```